# Zero results in Athena query of S3 object

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I placed a text file that is comma delimited in an S3 bucket. I am attempting to query the folder the file resides in but it returns zero results.

Create table DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myDatabase.myTable (
  `field_1` string,
  `field_2` string,
  ...
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://bucket/files from boss/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the whitespace in the location:

```
LOCATION 's3://bucket/files from boss/'
```

I removed the whitespace from the folder name in S3 and I was able to query without issue:

```
LOCATION 's3://bucket/files_from_boss/'
```